# Dividing values in a column of a data frame by values from a different data frame when row values match

Tags: r, plyr

I have a `data.frame` `x` with the following format:

```
     species      site  count
1:         A       1.1     25
2:         A       1.2   1152
3:         A       2.1     26
4:         A       3.5      1
5:         A       3.7     98
---                         
101:       B       1.2      6
102:       B       1.3     10
103:       B       2.1      8
104:       B       2.2      8
105:       B       2.3      5
```

I also have another `data.frame` `area` with the following format:

```
      species    area
1:          A    59.7
2:          B    34.4
3:          C    37.7
4:          D    22.8
```

I would like to divide the `count` column of `data.frame` `x` by values in the `area` column `data.frame` `area` when the values in the species column of each `data.frame` match

I have been trying to make it work with a `ddply` function:

```
density = ddply(x, "species", mutate, density = x$count/area[,2]
```

But I can't figure out the proper index syntax of the `area[]` call to select only the row which matches the values found in `x$species`. However, I am super new to the `plyr` package (and `apply*` functions as a whole) so this may be the completely wrong approach

I'm hoping to return a `data.frame` of the following format:

```
     species      site  count   density
1:         A       1.1     25     0.419
2:         A       1.2    152     2.546
3:         A       2.1     26     0.436
4:         A       3.5      1     0.017
5:         A       3.7     98     1.641
---                         
101:       B       1.2      6     0.174
102:       B       1.3     10     0.291
103:       B       2.1      8     0.233
104:       B       2.2      8     0.233
105:       B       2.3      5     0.145
```

Comment: Fyi, you are already using data.table, judging by how your data.frame prints out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#converting your data to the native type for the package (by reference)
setDT(x); setDT(area) 
x[area, density:=count/i.area, on="species"]
```

`:=` is the natural way to add columns in `data.table` (*by reference*, see [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) vignette & particularly point b) for some more about this and why it's important), so `x:=y` adds a column named `x` to your `data.table` and assigns it the value `y`.

When merging in the form `X[Y,]`, we can think of `Y` as selecting the rows of `X` to operate on; further, when `Y` is a `data.table`, all objects in both `X` and `Y` are avaiable in `j` (i.e., what comes after the comma), so we could have said `density:=count/area`; when we want to be *sure* that we're referring to one of `Y`'s columns, we prepend its name with `i.` so that we know we're referring to one of the columns in `i`, i.e., what precedes the comma. There should be a vignette on merges [forthcoming](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

In general, as soon as you think "match across different data sets" your instinct should be to merge. For more on `data.table`, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, although I have to admit, i don't understand the syntax the second argument of the last line. I mean, obviously it's creating the density column be dividng count and area. but what is the colon before the equals sign there for and why is the "i." preceding the area?

Comment: @C.Denney I've added some explanation. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a merge (`left_join`) then add new columns using `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% left_join(area, by="species") %>%
      mutate(density = count/area)
```

Comment: I know this answer is for 5 years ago, but I just wanted to say that your response saved me. Thanks